# Redirect from a Piwik campaign URL after counting the visit to avoid ugly URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal, drupal-6, matomo

In Piwik, [campaign URLs](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-campaigns/) look something like this:
http://example.org/landing.html?pk_campaign=Email-Nov2011

For a Drupal 6 site, I would like to use the campaign feature but at the same time avoid that URLs with the pk_campaign parameter spread to much.

My first thought was a header redirect through .htaccess, but that makes no sense since that would be before the Piwik tracking code is called. So it would need to be something like:

1. Call Piwik tracking code
2. Redirect to the URL without the pk_campaign parameter

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I came up with is using a javascript redirect right after the tracking code is displayed, but just in case the parameter pk_campaign is present. So I put the tracking code into the `<head>` section of the page and right after that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (location.search.indexOf('pk_campaign=')>=0)
  {
    document.location.href=location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname;
  }
</script>
```

That seems to work but is slower than a redirect through .htaccess oder PHP. Additionally it forces me to place the tracking code in the `<head>` and load it before the main content of the page.

Another option might be in PHP and htaccess. For example first redirecting to a count script (count.php) in case the URL contains the parameter pk_campaign (in .htaccess), something like this:

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pk_campaign
  RewriteRule ^ /count.php?url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Then in count.php something like the following using [PHP Output Control functions](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to avoid header errors:

```
<?php
  ob_start( );
?>

  <!-- Piwik tracking code here -->

<?php
  if (isset($_GET['pk_campaign'])) {
    ob_end_clean( );
    header( 'Location: ' . preg_replace('/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) );
    exit;
  }

  ob_end_flush( );
?>
```

I haven't really tried that, though. Somehow we'd have to "tell" Piwik the URL of the originating page, not the one the tracking code is in.